# ExceptionPolicy.HandleException does not install Event Source for Logging in Registry if XBAP run outside debugger

Tags: wpf, logging, enterprise-library, registry, xbap

I am using the Logging Application Block (of Microsoft Enterprise Library) to log exceptions in the Event Viewer that occur in my WPF XBAP application.

If I run the XBAP in the debugger from Visual Studio, an Event Source entry for my application is automatically created in the Registry at:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MyApp

This occurs at the point `ExceptionPolicy.HandleException()` is called.

However, if I run the XBAP outside of the IDE directly from the file system or from its published location, the Registry entry isn't added. Therefore, no logging takes place.

I can only assume this is a security issue with running XBAP applications and they do not have access to write to the Registry. Is this a setting within my project? Any idea on why this might be happening?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about it being a permission problem.

If you try to log to the event log and the event source does not exist the runtime will attempt to create a registry entry for the event source.  If you don't have permission then a `System.Security.SecurityException` with a message of "Requested registry access is not allowed." is thrown.  Enterprise Library catches this exception and attempts to log saying that it couldn't log the message.  If that also fails then the exception is swallowed.

The application is running in a [partial trust sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910.aspx) so wouldn't have permission to create registry keys.  You could try configuring the application to run as a [Full Trust Application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx).  Although [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/857815b7-ade2-4bbc-8047-e0bfad2d5d3b) says that there may still be a problem with that.

This issue also arises frequently when logging from ASP.NET and the usual solution is to create the required registry keys during the deployment process.  For WPF this feels a bit wrong, but is it possible to create a Windows Installer (.msi) that installs the registry keys?  Then the application wouldn't need to write to the registry (although it would still need to read from the registry so hopefully there is no permission problem with that!).

**UPDATE in response to comment**

As mentioned in the [URL above](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/857815b7-ade2-4bbc-8047-e0bfad2d5d3b):

> Yes, this is a design flaw in our
>   hosting process. You get "full trust"
>   from CLR point of view, but not in
>   terms of NT security. We'll try to
>   address this issue in a future
>   release.

I'm not sure if the issue has been resolved or not but it may be what you are seeing.

Comment: I've just checked and my application is definitely running as a full trust application ('This is a full trust application' selected in Security tab in Properties).

I can't really use a Windows Installer as the application is an XBAP, therefore users don't install the application, they simply access it via a URL in their browser.

It seems that the application is able to write to the Registry insofar as adding events to the Event Source. It just isn't able to create the folder in the Registry for the Event Source in the first instance.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It appears that running an XBAP in a browser results in limitations on event logging. Further information for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/857815b7-ade2-4bbc-8047-e0bfad2d5d3b
http://scorbs.com/2007/01/10/xbap-trust-levels/

Comment: @Neo, it may not be ideal but you could try using an event source you already know is set up (e.g. "Application").  That would only require read access to the registry which I believe you should have.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Wouldn't this result in the 'Source' column showing 'Application' though in Event Viewer? Like you said, this wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: @Neo: you're right. And you're right.  :)  Just an idea to try to get something working.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think, judging from the MSDN links I put earlier, it's a fundamental problem/blooper by Microsoft on XBAPs due to sandbox security, and we'll have to wait till Microsoft sort it out properly before we can do anything. For now, our XBAPs will have to make do without event logging unless we get each individual user to add a Registry key (which is not ideal).